# Arrows on top of a set of html tables?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a set of html tables (generated dynamically in my ReactJS code). 
An example is bellow: 
[image]

I want to draw arcs between some of the cells (specifically cells which have the same number). One idea is to create a transparent SVG and draw arrows in the SVG file. But the thing I am confused about is, how to specify start and end points of the arc (so that they align with the right cells). Anyone ideas for me?

Comment: Hacky, but what about getting positions of the cells (with jQuery for example) and drawing the arrows with CSS3 (absolutely positionned div - `width: length of arrow, height: 1px; transform: rotate`) ? That's how I did it there: http://epita-sma.github.io/ .

Comment: I suggest using [d3js](http://d3js.org/) to bind your data to the table. (its much simpler and a good intro to d3) Then, in your arrow generating code, assemble or update a second data set and use d3 to bind it to a set of new svg elements. In the code where d3 constructs the svg objects, you should be able to use the full data set to help position the arrows

Answer (score 1):

Answer linked to my comment : I had kind of the same need to draw a graph that I needed to have full control on for a school project (you can see the result [here](http://epita-sma.github.io))

I was using angular at the time, if you never have played with it, the `ng-repeat` attribute of the tag is just a `for` loop outputting the current dom element.

```
<div class="route"
     ng-repeat="route in routes"
     style="
       left: {{ route.source.x }}px;
       top: {{ route.source.y }}px;
       width: {{ route.distance }}px;
       transform: rotate({{ getAngle(route) }}rad);
       -webkit-transform: rotate({{ getAngle(route) }}rad);"
>▶</div>
```

The `getAngle` function is really simple:

```
Math.atan2((route.dest.y - route.source.y), (route.dest.x - route.source.x))
```

And here is the CSS of the `route` class:

```
.route {
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-bottom: -2px;
  text-align: right;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0px;
  transform-origin: 0 0px;
}
```

You'll probably have to fiddle a bit with the CSS to center everything, but here is the idea.